# Biome/nature board game- collecting animal cards from different environments

Tags: identify-this-game

My sisters and I have been trying to remember the name of a board game we used to play in the late 90s but have had no luck. Here are the details we remember:
1. Players had their own board themed for a biome/environment. I am really confident there was a rainforest board, and pretty confident that there was a savannah, grasslands, or prairie board.
2. Players had to collect the cards for their board. I think there were either 6 or 8 animals per board.
3. There was definitely a poison dart frog card (my sisters and I gave special weight to that card... we were weird kids haha).

I tried to Google the game but couldn't find it, probably because we remember so few details about it. I have already ruled out the game Explore.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do either of these look familiar: [Wildlife Adventure](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/156/wildlife-adventure), or [Wild life](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2311/wild-life)?  They seem to lack poison dart frogs and collection groups aren't based on biomes so I'm not optimistic, but they seem similar enough that I bet there's a relation somewhere.

Comment: Reminded me of this question: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/safari-ecology-childs-board-game-collecting-animal-cards

Comment: Unrelated but there are more games with poison dart frogs. So they must be awesome: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1156069/mighty-poison-dart-frog

Answer (score 1):

Would it perhaps be a variant of this Biomes Game? No poison dart frog; but it has some of the features you describe.

https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Biomes-Game-Full-Set-1888612